# Ajax status 0, success not firing, no info with the errors thrown

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I'm working on an app where the user enters info into a form, the form passes the info to my route, the route passes the info to the db, and then when done, it's supposed to update the page accordingly.

The issues I am having is that when you hit submit, the info **does** land on the database and gets saved but then on the callback/success/complete part of ajax, they dont fire and you have to hit a manual reload for the info to show up.  I'm going to assume that this is because of the readystate of 0.

I've tried many solutions other people here on SO have gotten but to no avail.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="createTodoFormW">
    <form method="post" id="createTodoForm">
        <input type="text" name="todoCompanyName" id="todoCompanyName" placeholder="Enter a Company name or leave empty if its a personal ToDo "><br>
        <input type="text" name="todoTitle" id="todoTitle" placeholder="Enter a Title for this note"><br>
        <input type="text" name="todoIsFor" id="todoIsFor" placeholder="Who is this ToDo for? ( If left empty, ToDo will be assigned to [ YOU ] )"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="todoPostedBy" id="todoPostedBy" value="LOGGED IN USER HERE">
        <input type="hidden" name="todoCompleted" id="todoCompleted" value="no">
        <input type="text" name="todoFirstMessage" id="todoFirstMessage" placeholder="Enter your ToDo message"><br>
        <select name="todoPriority" id="todoPriority">
            <option id="todoPriorityDefaultSelected" >Please select your ToDo priority</option>
            <option id="todoPrioritySelected" selected>green</option>
            <option id="todoPrioritySelected">yellow</option>
            <option id="todoPrioritySelected">red</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div><!-- createTodoFormW ender -->
```

express/node route:

```
app.post("/notesapi", (request, response) =>{

    //mongoose.connect(databaseLoc);

    const newNoteToAdd = new NotesModel({
        todoCompany : request.body.todoCompany, 
        todoIsFor : request.body.todoIsFor,  
        todoPostedBy : request.body.todoPostedBy, 
        todoCompleted : request.body.todoCompleted, 
        todoPriority : request.body.todoPriority, 
        todoMessages : request.body.todoMessages,
        todoTitle : request.body.todoTitle,
        todoDate : currDate
    });

    newNoteToAdd.save((err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log("There was an error uploading your data " + err);
        }else{
            //mongoose.connection.close();
            console.log("Data upload success.");
        }
    });
});
```

front end js:

```
$("#createTodoForm").submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url : "/notesapi",
        data : JSON.stringify({
            todoCompany : $("#todoCompanyName").val(), 
            todoTitle : $("#todoTitle").val(),
            todoPostedBy : $("#todoPostedBy").val(), 
            todoIsFor : $("#todoIsFor").val(),  
            todoMessages : $("#todoFirstMessage").val(),
            todoPriority : $("#todoPriority").val(), 
            todoCompleted : false
        }),
        success : function(){
            console.log("did ajax fire and comlete?");
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                        console.log("HTTP error (can be checked by XMLHttpRequest.status and XMLHttpRequest.statusText");
                    }
                    else if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
                        console.log("Network error (i.e. connection refused, access denied due to CORS, etc.");
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown)
                        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("something weird is happening");
                    }
                }    
    }); //ajax end

});
```

I need help. Been on this for days and cant figure it out. The main question i guess is, where is this state coming from and why doesnt my success function run?

thanks in advance for any assistance given.

Comment: `newNoteToAdd.save((err, data) => (err) ? response.status(500).send(err.message) : response.status(200).send('OK'))`?

Comment: Howdy Aikon. Thanks for the response but what is this supposed to do? i put it in and nothing happened?

Comment: You send `ajax`-query to Node.js. Node must process request and return response. Typically response is `response.status(200).send('Smth text or html')`. Your client side catch Node.response and call `success` or `error` function. If Node don't send response then your request will be waiting (you can see it in browser console).